# If in the input I give any character data why this will not going to throw section

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    cout << "Before try \n";
    try {
        cout << "Inside try \n";
        if (x <0)
        {
            throw x;
            //cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";
        }
    }
    catch (int x ) {
        cout << "Exception Caught \n";
    }
    catch (char x ) {
        cout << "Exception hjCaught \n";
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

If in the input I give any character data why this will not going to throw section. Is my code is wrong because it  works fine with the integer datatype.

Comment: Please elaborate on what do you mean by "_If in the input I give any character data_". Show us an example of the input, that's not working as expected.

Comment: If by *any character data* you mean you type something like "abc", why do you think that will make `x < 0` be true?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you added the last `catch (char x)` clause.

When the program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x;
  cin>>x;
  cout << "Before try \n";
  try {
    cout << "Inside try \n";
    if (x <0)
    {
       throw x;
       //cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";
    }
  }
  catch (int x ) {
    cout << "Exception Caught \n";
  }
}
```

It seems to work:

- positive numbers won't throw exception
- negative numbers throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

As per according to this program, it will throw the exception when *positive numbers*.

But when you will enter the `char` input in the `int` variable then there will be an input failure and there will be `0` in the x.

You can check it by using this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "x is " << x << endl;
    }
    cout << "Before try \n";
    try
    {
        cout << "Inside try \n";
        if (x < 0)
        {
            throw x;
            //cout << "After throw (Never executed) \n";
        }
    }
    catch (int x)
    {

        cout << "Exception Caught \n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program output on the char input will be

> a
>
> x is 0
>
> Before try
>
> Inside try

As the x will have 0 so it will not throw exception as the condition is *x<0*

Comment: Note that a value of `0` (or min/max of the type if input is too small/large) is only guaranteed in C++11 or later: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). Before that: *If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.*

Comment: *Yes, Thank you .As the value is not guaranteed but while running test cases it was 0.*